# Installing elasticsearch, getting error

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm trying to install elastic search. Downloaded the bat file form here:
https://www.elastic.co/downloads/elasticsearch

I'm getting following error:

```
D:\elasticsearch\bin>elasticsearch.bat
Error: Could not find or load main class D:\elasticsearch\lib\elasticsearch-cli
6.2.4.jar
```

The jar is already there under lib.

My java version is:

```
D:\elasticsearch\bin>java -version
java version "1.8.0_141"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_141-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.141-b15, mixed mode)
```

Any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Did you check in D:\elasticsearch\lib to see if elasticsearch-cli-6.2.4.jar is there?

Comment: Yes the Jar is there.